# jsrender - How to pass javascript literal object to a custom tag?

Tags: jsrender

Is it possible to pass a javascript literal object to a custom tag in jsrender?
for example something like this:

```
{{tag parameter={width: 200, 
                 click: function(){
                            alert('clicked');
                      }
                } 
/}}
```

Comment: you call the tags without named parameters (e.g. {{tag {field: 'hello'} \}}) but I can't make it work using jsfiddle.  I get a parse error: http://jsfiddle.net/pedz/N2kmj/9/ (which you can see via firebug)

Comment: My example does not work in jsrender. I just want to know if it is possible in some way to pass a literal object to a custom tag.

Comment: Yea.  I understand your question.  I don't know the answer.  Sorry.  Boris monitors this and might reply.  I will also play with it on my free time.  Right now, it looks like it isn't possible.  The odd thing is that passing a string works but passing an object literal does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it is not supported, assuming you don't set `allowCode=true`. JsRender templates are supposed to be side-effect free. A javascript literal `{}` is creating a new Object() so is not side-effect free. But you can pass in any object you want via template parameters/helpers. Many ways to to do that, e.g. declaring helpers on the template, declaring global helpers, passing in as an option in the `.render(data, options)` call... Then you just write `{{tag parameter=~myPassedInObject}}`. You can also have a helper that returns different objects, such as `{{tag parameter=~myWidthObject(200,...)}}`,